# how to repeat taking input until expected value

Tags: python

```
def n_g():
   ...:     first_input = input("are you okay?")
   ...:     if first_input == "good":
   ...:         if input("are you sure") == "Yes":
   ...:             return "Nice"
   ...:         return ???
   ...:     return n_g()
```

I want this part of code can let customer answer the question again and again until they say "yes". What I should put at ???

Comment: What about replace the `return ???` with `n_g()`?

Comment: I think it will restart at the beginning, while I want customers to answer the second question again and again until they say "yes" instead of restarting at the first question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use another function to confirm

```
def conf():
    if input("are you sure") == "Yes":
        return True
    return conf()

def n_g():
    first_input = input("are you okay?")
    if first_input == "good":
        # this method will return if you say only "yes"
        conf()
        return "Nice"
    else:
        return n_g()
```

Comment: sorry, I am required not to use loop, and this actually is one if statement, I have question about how to return to the second input again and again(there is a smaller if-statement under the first one) in stead of calling the main function to return to the beginning

Comment: @Ryan, Can you check?

Comment: Thanks man, it is actually helpful by using a helper. And I think there is no way to write this without the helper

Answer (score 2):

you can learn about iteration, it's recursive thinking

```
def n_g():
    first_input = input("are you okay?")
    if first_input == "yes":
        print("Nice")
    else:
        n_g()
```

Comment: It's Recursive thinking, sorry for Spelling mistakes

Comment: Could you tell me what the error it is? I can run it in python3.6 on pycharm

Comment: Err, never mind. I was entering `Yes`, and not `yes`. ;)

Comment: My mistake T_T @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: this actually is one if statement, I have question about how to return to the second input again and again(there is a smaller if-statement under the first one) in stead of calling the main function to return to the beginning

Comment: He is not supposed to start full process again. Just second part.

Answer (score 1):

you wrote "Yes" instead of "yes" in your code....hence you need to make change there also for the main part you may call the function again

```
 def n_g():
        first_input = input("are you okay?")
        if first_input == "good":
            if input("are you sure") == "yes":
                return "Nice"
            return n_g()
        return n_g()
```

Comment: You should use `.lower()`

Comment: He is not supposed to start full process again. Just second part.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to just restart at "are you sure" when I pass the first one and fail the second one, your code will always restart at the beginning even if you pass the first question and stop at the second one

Comment: Oh in that case you  may modify the function little bit i am answering again it might help

Answer (score 0):

```
def n_g(check):
    if check == False:
        first_input = input("are you okay?")
    else:
        first_input = "good"
    if first_input == "good":
        if input("are you sure") == "yes":
            return "Nice"
        return n_g(True)
    return n_g(False)
```

> > > n_g(False)